# Navigating among three screens

Tags: react-native

I am about to making an app with React Native and I have three screens with deferent styles (themes). I want to navigate among these three screens, So I am passing data from my main screen (App.js) as parent to the other three as child (screen1, screen2, screen3). I used a modal which has three button in it and i want whenever I pressed one of them, the screen change to the pressed one. This is  my App.js file

```
    import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
    import { StyleSheet, View } from "react-native";
    
    import Screen1 from "./screens/CalcScreen";
    import Screen2 from "./screens/Screen1";
    import Screen3 from "./screens/Screen2";
    
    export default function App() {
      const [whiteScreen, setWhiteScreen] = useState(false);
      const [darkScreen, setDarkScreen] = useState(false);
      const [pinkScreen, setPinkScreen] = useState(false);
    
      const whiteScreenHandler = () => {
        setWhiteScreen(true);
        setDarkScreen(false);
        setPinkScreen(false);
      };
      const darkScreenHandler = () => {
        setDarkScreen(true);
        setWhiteScreen(false);
        setPinkScreen(false);
      };
      const pinkScreenHander = () => {
        setPinkScreen(true);
        setWhiteScreen(false);
        setDarkScreen(false);
      };
      let content = <screen1 setDarkScreen={darkScreenHandler} />;
      let content2 = <Screen2 setWhiteScreen={whiteScreenHandler} />;
      let content3 = <Screen3 setPinkScreen={pinkScreenHander} />;
    
      if (darkScreen) {
        content = content;
      } else if (whiteScreen) {
        content = content2;
      } else if (pinkScreen) {
        content = content3;
      }
      return <View style={styles.container}>{content}</View>;
    }
    
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: "#374351",
      },
    });
```

And this is one of my screens and my modals in my screens, the other two screens are same in coding but not in styles and I used this modal in each three screens,(does it right to use in three screens?) anyway whenever I'm pressing modal's button to change the screens i got props.screen handler() is not a function. What is wrong in my code?

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  ScrollView,
  View,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Alert,
  Animated,
  Modal,
  Pressable,
} from "react-native";

const Screen1 = (props) => {
return (
    <View style={styles.screen}>
      <Modal
          animationType="slide"
          transparent={true}
          visible={modalVisible}
          onRequestClose={() => {
            setModalVisible(!modalVisible);
          }}
        >
          <View style={styles.centeredView}>
            <View style={styles.modalView}>
              <View style={styles.button}></View>
              <Text style={styles.modalText}>Themes</Text>

              <TouchableOpacity
                style={styles.darkTheme}
                onPress={() => {
                  props.setDarkScreen();
                }}
              >
                <Text>Dark</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
              <TouchableOpacity
                style={styles.whiteTheme}
                onPress={() => {
                  props.setWhiteScreen();
                }}
              >
                <Text>White</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
              <TouchableOpacity
                style={styles.pinkTheme}
                onPress={() => {
                  props.setPinkScreen();
                }}
              >
                <Text>Pink</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
              <Pressable
                style={[styles.buttonClose]}
                onPress={() => setModalVisible(!modalVisible)}
              >
                <Text style={styles.textStyle}>X</Text>
              </Pressable>
            </View>
          </View>
        </Modal>
        <Pressable
          style={[styles.button, styles.buttonOpen]}
          onPress={() => setModalVisible(true)}
        >
          <Text style={styles.openText}>{">"}</Text>
        </Pressable>
    </View>
)
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  screen: {
    backgroundColor: "#fafcff",
  },
centeredView: {
    // flex: 1,
    marginStart: 15,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    // marginTop: 70,
  },
  modalView: {
    marginTop: 200,
    backgroundColor: "rgba(255,255,255,0.5)",
    borderRadius: 20,
    padding: 20,
    alignItems: "center",
    shadowColor: "#000",
    shadowOffset: {
      width: 0,
      height: 2,
    },
    shadowOpacity: 0.5,
    shadowRadius: 4,
    elevation: 5,
  },
  button: {
    borderRadius: 15,
    padding: 10,
    elevation: 2,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    marginTop: 20,
  },
  buttonOpen: {
    backgroundColor: "rgba(1,143,132,0.6)",
    position: "absolute",
    marginTop: 45,
    marginStart: -25,
    elevation: 2,
    height: 70,
    width: 40,
  },
  buttonClose: {
    backgroundColor: "rgba(1,1,1,1)",
    height: 40,
    width: 40,
    borderRadius: 50,

    // padding: 10,
    elevation: 2,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    marginTop: 20,
  },
  textStyle: {
    color: "white",
    // fontWeight: "bold",
    textAlign: "center",
  },
  modalText: {
    marginBottom: 10,
    textAlign: "center",
  },
  openText: {
    fontSize: 25,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    color: "white",
    textAlign: "right",
  },
});
export default Screen1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily doing that by using "React Native Navigation". Here is the documentation:
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started. I also recommend you that you might want to create your screens into different files to make your code cleaner.